# Can’t connect to wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, wifi-driver

I’m using a PCIe wifi card and this morning it stopped working. Last night it was working fine but when I turned my pc on this morning it doesn’t show any wifi networks, I’ve tried restarting my pc but it didn’t help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check in Device Manager if the Wireless Network card is there? If it has a red or yellow X?   Run the Manufacturer's Hardware Diagnostic App.  Try re-installing the Wireless Driver.

Comment: I checked device manager and it doesn’t show up there at all

Comment: I would try and see if it shows up in BIOS/UEFI first.  If not, I would next try it on another known working mobo, then vice versa working card on that slot.  This should definitively answer if it's a hardware issue.

Comment: go to device manager and uninstall all network adapters on by one then reboot the system, Did that fix?

Comment: I know this a late reply but here it is anyway. I tried all the options that were given and none of them worked, however it appears to be a hardware problem because I tried a different card and it worked just fine. I’m using Ethernet now anyway but thanks to everyone who tried to help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I’m using a PCIe wifi card and this morning it stopped working. I
> checked device manager and it doesn’t show up there at all –

The card very most likely has a hardware problem and has failed. It needs to be replaced.

It is possible it needs to be re-seated

Either service it yourself or take the computer to a local shop to have it replaced.